# Como criar schema e utilizá-lo na criação de tabela

Tags: sql-server

Preciso criar umas tabelas, mas que tenha essa estrutura.
Para as tabelas de Cadastros eu coloco:

Cadastro.Empresa, Cadastro.UF, Cadastro.Endereçoe eassim sucessivamente.
Para as tabelas de Logo eu faço:
Log.Acessos, Log.Erros
Para as tabelas de Dominio eu teria
Dominio.TipoPessoa, Dominio.TipoUsuario e assim por diante. Acontece que me dá esse erro:

> Mensagem 2760, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 2
>
> O nome do esquema especificado 'Cadastro' não existe ou  você não tem
>   permissão para usá-lo.

Esse erro veio a partir desse comando(apenas testes, por isso não tem chaves primária e etc...):

```
create table Cadastro.UF(IDUf integer, Sigla_UF char(2), Nome_Uf varchar(18));
```

Como eu crio um schema para utilizar dessa forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja procurando pelo comando [`CREATE SCHEMA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx)

```
USE MeuDatabase;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA Cadastro AUTHORIZATION MeuUsuario; 
GO
```

Você também pode querer dar permissões para outros usuários que pretendem utilizar o `SCHEMA`:

```
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::Cadastro TO MeuOutroUsuario;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::Cadastro TO AindaOutroUsuario;
```